# How to do vertical sorting in the equation?

Tags: vertical-alignment, empheq

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{array}
I_1\cdot(R_1 + R_4)+I_2\cdot R_1 +I_3\cdot 0 =\varepsilon_1\\
I_1\cdot R_1 + I_2\cdot(R_1+R_2+R_5) +I_3\cdot R_5 =\varepsilon_1\\
I_1\cdot 0 + I_2\cdot R_5+I_3\cdot(R_3 + R_5)=\varepsilon_2
\end{array}


\begin{array}
I_3=I_1+I_2\\
\downarrow  \downarrow&  \downarrow \\
\dfrac{U_1}{R_4}=\dfrac{\varepsilon_1-U_1}{R_1}+\dfrac{U_2-U_1}{R_2}
\end{array}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: If I add a documentclass and the missing packages to your code, it is not compilable. Also the code does not match the shown screenshot. Could you therefore please make your code compilable. Please also explain why you use `empheq` for this.

Comment: (i) please extend your code snippet to MWE (ii) if i guess correctly what is your problem, than instead of `empheq` try to use `array` ...

Comment: What do you mean by `vertical sorting` in the equation?

Comment: @leandriis, I wrote MWE this way so it was short. the `empheq` was wrong.

Comment: @Bernard, the question title can be changed. I may be insufficient in technical language. I did the necessary corrections and additions.

Comment: I still do not understand what the problem is; Could you explain?

Comment: @Bernard, I wanted to write down all 'I_1', 'I_2' and 'I_3' characters for three equations. The second is like this. Did I explain? If not, If you give me some time, I'il try to explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of the `array` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\[
\begin{array}{c@{~\cdot~}c@{~+~}c@{~\cdot~}c@{~+~}c@{~\cdot~}c@{~=~}c}
R_1 + R_4 & I_1 & R_1         & I_2 & 0         & I_3 & \varepsilon_1\\
R_1       & I_1 & R_1+R_2+R_5 & I_2 & R_5       & I_3 & \varepsilon_1\\
0         & I_1 & R_5         & I_2 & R_3 + R_5 & I_3 & \varepsilon_2
\end{array}
\]

\[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
I_3             & = & I_1                            & + & I_2\\
\downarrow      &   & \downarrow                     &   &  \downarrow \\
\dfrac{U_1}{R_4}& = & \dfrac{\varepsilon_1-U_1}{R_1} & + & \dfrac{U_2-U_1}{R_2}
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't resist proposing another layout for the first group of three equations, obtained with `pstricks`: as there more or less wide blank spaces between groups, I placed the `+` signs in the centre of each  of these blank spaces:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pst-node, multido, auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{postscript}
\[ \begin{array}{lrr}
I_1 \cdot (R_1 + R_4)\pnode{A1} & \pnode{B1} R_1 \cdot I_2 \pnode{C1}& \pnode{D1}0 \cdot I_3 =\varepsilon_1\\[1ex]
I_1 \cdot R_1 \pnode{A2} & \pnode{B2} (R_1+R_2+R_5) \cdot I_2 \pnode{C2} & \pnode{D2} R_5 \cdot I_3 =\varepsilon_1\\[1ex]
I_1 \cdot 0 \pnode{A3}&\pnode{B3} R_5 \cdot I_2\pnode{C3} &\enspace \pnode{D3} (R_3 + R_5) \cdot I_3 =\varepsilon_2
\end{array} \]
\psset{offset =\fontdimen22\textfont2,linestyle=none}
\multido{\i =1+1}{3}{\ncline{A\i}{B\i}\ncput*{+}\ncline{C\i}{D\i}\ncput*{+}}
\end{postscript}

\end{document}
```

[image]